# Confusing sentry error - user is routed to search from login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, error-handling, ruby-on-rails-4, sentry

I have a social dating Rails 4 website that triggered a Sentry error. In a search controller that returns the closest users within a certain radius:

The exception is *NoMethodError undefined method `page' for nil:NilClass* and is related to the following line of code:

```
current_user.longitude).users.page(params[:page]).per(20)
```

The referrer URL in this request was something.com/login and this request URL was something.com/search.  The "page" method comes from the [Kaminari gem](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari), a pagination gem.  The user logs in and is redirected to a profile page where they can click a "Search" button.  My question is: what could possibly be triggering this error and/or why does /search have a referrer URL of /login?  There's no search button on the login page.  When I test everything manually, everything works as it should.

EDIT: The issue is that the referrer URL is /login on the /search action that is causing the error.  However, a person logging in will not be directed to the search action they will be redirected to a profile page where they can then click on the Search button.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is not in the `Kaminary`, it says "undefined method for *nil*", which means, the `users` method for some reason returns `nil`, that's what you want to check

Comment: thanks Nikolay.  I edited above to make the question more clear.  You're right about the user being nil, but the issue is that the referrer URL appears to be /login which can't happen because once a user logs in they are redirected to a profile page, not a search action.  That is what I'm puzzled about